# How do I "unstringify" a value within an array with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a dynamic search query for a Mongo database.

In short, and not directly related to the question... it looks like this:

```
var searchCriteria = {}; <-- start with empty object    

return db.users.find(searchCriteria,
    { sort: { username: 1 }
});
```

The values for searchCriteria come from a search form, basically like this:

```
var filter = $(form).find('select[name=filter]').val();
var query = $(form).find('[name=query]').val();

searchCriteria[filter] = query <-- Using a dynamic key
```

Example output from the form:

```
console.log(searchCriteria);
>> { username: "jdoe" }
```

So here's my hangup. I need to "unstringify" the query within the searchCriteria, and turn it into this:

```
>> { username: /jdoe/ }
```

I've tried replace, among other things, but it keeps ending up as a string value. I need the /query/ in that format for the Mongo find query.

Any suggestions? Thank you :)

Comment: Huh? Are you trying to turn a string into a Regex? If so, just `new RegExp(string);`

Comment: Just FYI `{}` is an empty *object*, not an empty array.

Comment: `var searchCriteria = {};` is not an array, its an object

Comment: is there a reason why you need this ? may there is a option for other possibilitys to solve this if we know what you want to do with it :)

Comment: @ZekeSonxx I can't believe I missed this... How embarrassing. Please post as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @Dwza - My problem is solved thanks for Zeke. I missed the obvious on new RegExp()

Comment: dont forget input.replace(/([.+?^\-*=!:${(})\|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily turn a string into a RegExp object by using `new Regex(string)`.

Note that this is bound to have some security issues somewhere if you're passing in user input, but `new RegExp` shouldn't allow any arbitrary JS to run, but it could still crash your code by being an invalid Regex.

[Source (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: someone should probably mention something  about escaping special chars and sanitizing user input.

Comment: @dandavis Good call. In my case, it's a protected admin page on a site.

Comment: @dandavis Hah. Me either :)